# Почему меняется значение переменной, которую не менял

Tags: python, numpy

```
# корректируем центроиды Xc 
def move_centroids(x,xc,c):
    for k in range(len(c)):
        # собираем номера точек X из кластера номер k
        ik = c[k]
        if ik.shape[0] > 0 :
            # собираем точки X из кластера номер k
            xk = x[ik,:]
            # корректируем центроид xc кластера номер k
            xc[k,:] = np.mean(xk,axis=0)
    return xc
def k_means(x,xc,delta):
    MAX_ITER=100 
    for i in range(MAX_ITER):
        xc_previous = xc
        R = build_dist_matrix_centroids(x,xc)
        C = build_clusters(R)
        xc = move_centroids(x,xc_previous ,C)
        # если изменение состояния незначительно то завершаем работу
        d = np.sum(metric(xc_previous,xc))
        print('%i/%i : %f   \r'%(i,MAX_ITER,d))
        if d < delta : break

    # удаляем пустые кластеры
    return np.array([value for value in xc if value != [] ])
```

Проблема заключается в том, что я запоминаю значение `xc`  в `xc_previous` и меняю `xc`, а на выходе значение `xc_previous` меняется вместе с `xc`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это особенность работы с numpy-массивами. Несколько моментов.

1. При "запоминании" значения `numpy.array` следует использовать `numpy.copy()`, иначе запоминается не значение, а ссылка на значение.
2. В вашей функции `move_centroids` есть параметр `xc`, который также
   возвращается в конце. То есть при вызове `move_centroids(x,xc,C)`, значение переданного параметра `xc` будет изменено и писать `xc = move_centroids(x,xc,C)` - нет смысла.

Получается вам надо сделать следующие изменения:

1. `xc_previous = xc` -> `xc_previous = np.copy(xc)`
2. `xc = move_centroids(x,xc_previous ,C)` -> `move_centroids(x,xc ,C)`